# How is a pointer to a member function different than a pointer to a data member?

Tags: c++, pointer-to-member

So I have this alias template:

```
template<class MemberT, class ClassT>
using make_member_ptr = MemberT ClassT::*;
```

And I noticed that `make_member_ptr<int(char, long), class_type>` is the same that `int(class_type::*)(char, long)`. Before, I was thinking that a pointer to a member function is completely different to a pointer to a data member.

How do pointers to member functions differ from pointers to data members?

The only thing that I could find is that if the member function is virtual, calling through a pointer to the base function will call the derived function, which is a non-issue for pointers a non-function member.

The reason I am asking is that I am dealing with generic pointers to members, and I want to know what I have to look out for and special case for pointers to member functions vs data members.

Comment: Why do you believe they are the same? `MemberT ClassT::*` is not even syntactically the same as `MemberT (ClassT::*)()`.

Comment: @WernerHenze Here, it is like `using MemberT = int()`, and `std::is_same_v<make_member_ptr<int(), class_type>, int(class_type::*)()>` is true.

Comment: @Artyer They are just as different as pointers to ordinary functions and pointers to ordinary objects.

Comment: @WernerHenze Well, it kind of is... it just looks like it isn't because of C's esoteric spiral rule for distributing aspects of the type around the name (which, here, is zero-length)

Comment: @Artyer OK, understood, that surprises me as well. MSVC tells me that it expands `make_member_ptr<int(), T>` to `int (T::*)()`. I would have expected it to not compile (like `int () T::*`) does not compile.

Comment: Pointers to functions can be a different size than pointers to data.  Member functions can be virtual, whereas data members can only be virtual by the use of virtual inheritance (which is really consolidation, and not polymorphism).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Before, I was thinking that a pointer to a member function is completely different to a pointer to a data member.

You've thought correctly.

> How do pointers to member functions differ from pointers to data members?

They are separate types. They may have different sizes. Pointer to a member function can point to a member function. Pointer to a data member can point to a data member. The difference is analogous to the one between function pointers and data pointers.

`make_member_ptr<int(char, long), class_type>` is a pointer to member function.