# how is pointer to member able to bind to T U::*

Tags: c++, pointer-to-member

I was going through [`std::is_member_pointer` in cpprefernce](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_member_pointer).

```
template< class T >
struct is_member_pointer_helper         : std::false_type {};
 
template< class T, class U >
struct is_member_pointer_helper<T U::*> : std::true_type {};
 
template< class T >
struct is_member_pointer : 
    is_member_pointer_helper<typename std::remove_cv<T>::type> {};

int main() {
    class cls {};
    std::cout << (std::is_member_pointer<int cls::*>::value
                     ? "T is member pointer"
                     : "T is not a member pointer") << '\n';
    std::cout << (std::is_member_pointer<int(cls::*)(int, int)>::value
                     ? "T is member pointer"
                     : "T is not a member pointer") << '\n';
}
```

Ouput:

```
T is member pointer
T is member pointer
```

How are `int cls::*` and `int(cls::*)(int, int)` both bind to `T U::*` in `struct is_member_pointer_helper<T U::*>`?

For `int cls::*` `T` is `int` and `U` is `cls` and for `int(cls::*)(int)` what are `T` and `U`? I went through this [question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54503321/12582758) which has the below code:

```
template<class MemberT, class ClassT>
using make_member_ptr = MemberT ClassT::*;

class A {
public:
    void member() { }
};

int main()
{   
    make_member_ptr<int, A> ptr;
    make_member_ptr<void(), A> fptr;
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<int A::*, decltype(ptr)>);
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(fptr), void(A::*)()>);
    return 0;
}
```

Like werner pointer in the comments how is `make_member_ptr<void(), A>` expands to `void (A::*)()`

[link to the code](https://godbolt.org/z/7ejrK7vGM)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easier to understand if you spell the types with words.

`T U::*` is a "pointer to member of class `U` that has type `T`".

`int(cls::*)(int, int)` is a "pointer to member of class `cls` that has type 'a function with parameters `(int, int)`, returning `int`'".

Hence `U` is `cls`, and `T` is a "function with parameters `(int, int)`, returning `int`", aka `int(int, int)`.

Comment: Thank you. How does `make_member_ptr<void(), A>` expand to `void(A::*)()`? I'm getting error when I try to write [`static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(fptr), void()(A::*)>);`](https://godbolt.org/z/dq3hGsajY).

Comment: @Yelp `void()(A::*)` is not a valid type, for the same reason that `int[4] var;` is not valid, or `int(int) func;`. In C++, we write array sizes and function parameters on the right. If you start with "pointer to member of `A`" (aka `A::*`), and want to make it a pointer to function, you add the parameters on the right: `(A::*)()`, then the return type: `void (A::*)()`. Notice the extra parentheses around `A::*` which are required because `()` has higher precedence than `A::*`, so `void A::*()` would be a "function returning `A::*`".

Comment: Got it. I'm not able to understand this part `using make_member_ptr = MemberT ClassT::*;` when `MemberT` is `void()` and `ClassT` is `A`. Why  is it being expanded as `void(A::*)()`, if literally substituted it would be `void() A::*`?

Comment: Is it that when `MemberT` is a function C++ does something else internally?

Comment: @Yelp It's not substituted literally. It's helpful to convert the types to plain english first, then substitue, then convert back, like I do in the answer.

Comment: @Yelp For the "C++ -> English" instructions, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66617894/c-syntax-understanding-issue-for-using/66618546#66618546

Comment: `for the same reason that int[4] var; is not valid, or int(int) func;` Now it completly makes sense. Thank you so much. I re-read it now it makes sense completly. Thank you for time and patience. :)